Filling a closed curve
Background
Consider the following surface on $\mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{equation}\mathcal{S}\triangleq \{\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\}_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in [0,1]}\end{equation}
for some suitable map $\psi:[0,1]^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider its boundary
\begin{equation}\partial \mathcal{S}\triangleq \{\psi_\text{c}(\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in [0,1]}\end{equation}
for some suitable map $\psi_{\text{c}}:[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that $\mathcal{S}$ is simply connected and $\partial \mathcal{S}$ is closed. If my intuition is not wrong, it should be possible to identify $\partial \mathcal{S}$ from $\mathcal{S}$ and vice versa.
In one direction - i.e from $\mathcal{S}$ to $\partial \mathcal{S}$ - is pretty easy to prove my claim. In the other direction - i.e from $\partial \mathcal{S}$ to $\mathcal{S}$ -  I find some difficulties.
proof
I prove that is possible to obtain the boundary parametrization $\psi_\text{c}(\alpha)$ given the surface parametrization $\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$.
To do that, note that it is sufficient to restrict  $\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ to the boundary of $[0,1]^2$. Hence,
\begin{equation*}
\psi_{\text{c}}(\alpha)\triangleq \psi(\gamma_{\text{c}1}(\alpha), \gamma_{\text{c}2}(\alpha)) \qquad \alpha\in[0,1]
\end{equation*}
where the parametrization of the boundary of $[0,1]^2$ is
\begin{equation*}
\gamma_\text{c}(\alpha)=\left[\begin{array}{c}\gamma_{\text{c}1}(\alpha) \\ \gamma_{\text{c}2}(\alpha)\end{array}\right]\triangleq
\begin{cases}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
4 \left(\alpha-\frac{0}{4}\right) & 0
\end{array}\right]' & \text{if } \alpha \in [0/4, 1/4) \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 4 \left(\alpha-\frac{1}{4}\right) 
\end{array}\right]' & \text{if } \alpha \in [1/4, 2/4) \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1-4 \left(\alpha-\frac{2}{4}\right) & 1
\end{array}\right]' & \text{if } \alpha \in [2/4, 3/4) \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1-4 \left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)
\end{array}\right]' & \text{if } \alpha \in [3/4, 4/4] \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and $'$ is the transpose operator.
Question
If it is possible, given $\psi_\text{c}(\alpha)$, how do you define a parametrization $\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ that covers all points in $\mathcal{S}$?
My attempt
I'm tempted to define
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\triangleq \alpha_2 (\psi_\text{c}(\alpha_1)-p)+p
\qquad \alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in [0,1]
\end{equation*}
where $p$ is the boundary center, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
p \triangleq \frac{\int_0^1 \psi_{\text{c}}(\alpha) \lVert \dot{\psi}_\text{c}(\alpha)\rVert \text{ d}\alpha}{\int_0^1 \lVert \dot{\psi}_\text{c}(\beta)\rVert \text{ d}\beta}
\qquad \dot{z}(\alpha)\triangleq \frac{\text{d}\psi_{\text{c}}}{\text{d}\alpha}
\end{equation*}
but I'm not sure if $\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ covers all point in $\mathcal{S}$.
EDIT
I'm interested in the case where $\mathcal{S}$ is not star-convex.

Given a smooth simple loop $C$ in $E^3$, either it does not bound an embedded disk (i.e. $C$ is a nontrivial knot) or it bounds continuum of distinct smoothly embedded disks. Start by working out the example of $C$ which is a round circle and disks are contained in various round spheres.

It appears, from your "I'm tempted to define...", that you are seeking some function that extends the known function on the boundary over the interior, but your question asks how to actually recover a particular function (which is impossible). Consider the analogous situation in 1D: I have a function $f:[-1, 1] \to \mathbb R$, and it satisfies $f(-1) = -1$ and $f(1) = 1$. I'd like you to guess what $f(x)$ is for $-1 < x < 1$. You can't do it, because my $f$ could be $f(x) = x^3$ or $f(x) = x^5$, or any of many other possibilities!

You are absolutely right. My question is imprecise: given $\psi_{\text{c}}(\alpha)$, I want to define a possible parametrization $\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ that covers all internal points $\mathcal{S}$ of the closed curve $\partial \mathcal{S}$.

There are many ways. You could try to solve Laplace's equation in the square $[0, 1]^2$ with the given $\psi_c$ function as boundary condition.
